# Detect end of Download - Using href

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, dom

Hi I would detect the end of the download of my file. The file is generated by a php method.

I tryed 3 ways in js : 
 - two download the file
 - one detect the end of php script

## 1

```
function downloadTcReport(e, flag) {
e.preventDefault ? e.preventDefault() : e.returnValue = false;
window.location.href = "Phpz/download_tc.php?method=download_tc_report";
```

}

## 2

```
function downloadURL(url) {
var hiddenIFrameID = 'hiddenDownloader',
        iframe = document.getElementById(hiddenIFrameID);
if (iframe === null) {
    iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    iframe.id = hiddenIFrameID;
    iframe.style.display = 'none';
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);
}
iframe.src = url;
```

}

## 3

```
jQuery(e).load("Phpz/download_tc.php?method=download_tc_all_current_cl", function() {

            alert("Win !!!");
        });
```

and a part of my php code

```
if (@$_GET['method'] == 'download_tc_report') {
        $obj = new downloadTC();
        $content = $obj->get_last_report();
        header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
        header("Content-Length: " . strlen($content));
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"tc_report.csv\"");
        echo $content;
    }
```

With the code #1 and #2 I download correctly the file without change location but I can't detect the end of generation of my file

With the code #3 I detect the end but put the string content of my file in the "e" element past on the function. Or nothing if no element .

So I need to download a file who are not generated yet and detect when the file is sending (example of use: the user click on a button, a loading div appear and disappear after the generation is completed )
Some one have an idea to help me?

Thanks

EDIT :

```
function downloadURL(url) {

jQuery.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    beforeSend: function() {
        console.log("Begin");
    },
    success: function() {
        console.log("End");
    }
    ,
    error: function() {

    }
});
```

This function  not working too.
Detect the end and the beginning but not open the download (like when you download a excel file and it asks to you if you want open it with Office... on win)

Comment: I don't think there's a way for JS to monitor downloads.

Comment: If you use http protocol then simply look for 200 answer in ajax

Comment: If you don't want the content of file to show in e. element you could easy make use af `.ajax()` and the `.success()` method ...http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ . As @Robert says, you could easily look for code status fore response

Comment: You can monitor when something has `.load`ed when its inline -- that means it's part of the DOM, and JavaScript can see it. If you're downloading it separately, that can't be monitored by JavaScript.

Comment: That's not working I receive all data but they don't ask to me to open the file (file can be huge, I don't want to stock the content in php or js buffer)